# NSTableView setup to automatically resize middle column?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsview, nstablecellview

Is it possible to set up a `NSTableView` with e.g. 4 columns in IB to allow just one column to resize when the table grows?

So far I couldn't achieve this with neither **Resizing:** *Autoresizes* or decreasing content hugging value for the `TableCellView` in the column that should be the only one that grows when the table is resized.

Is there any way to convince a particular column - not just the last one - to just '*let go*' and resize with its `NSTableView`..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the xib, go to each column object and in the column object's attribute inspector set resizing to: None. Set resizing on the column you want to 'let go' to: Autoresizes with Table.

Comment: Problem was I had **2** columns set to *Autoresizes with..*. On only 1 column it works just fine.